# Deleting certain data from a file

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have a file stored in my system and I want to delete certain data from it.

I accomplish this by making a temporary file, then write all of the original file data to it, but without the data I don't want. Then, I rename that temporary file with the same name of the original file in order to replace it.

Everything goes so well, except there is a problem with deleting the original file and renaming the temporary file.

At first, I had the original file with data, then after running the application I had the original file with the same data without any deletion, and the temporary file named (file) with the data after deletion.

Here's the method I'm using:

```
public void remove(String path, String link, String ext) throws IOException {

    File file = new File(path);
    File temp = File.createTempFile("file", ext, file.getParentFile());
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), charset));
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(temp), charset));

    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
        line = line.replace(link, "");
        writer.println(line);
    }

    reader.close();
    writer.close();
    file.delete();
    temp.renameTo(file);
}
```

Comment: What "*temp file don't obey the rename instruction*" actually means?

Comment: means that the temp file remains with it's name and the original file remains in the system without deletion

Comment: in first i had original file with data, then after running the application i had the original file with the same data without any deletion and the temp file named (file) with the data after deletion

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: no there is no exceptions and the code run normally

Comment: Both delete() and renameTo() return boolean success values, so you should try checking those to see if the methods are even succeeding. Try if(file.delete()) System.out.println("Delete unsuccessful");  It's also possible that since the delete is failing, it is causing your renameTo to fail, since it will always fail if there's a pre-existing file of that name, which would be the case is your file.delete fails

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?  If you're on 1.7, the new [`java.file.nio`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) package can (and will) make this operation very painless.

Comment: well,i checked the original file and found that it didn't deleted, what can make this issue and what can i do to ensure the deletion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to check the return value of `delete()`. If the old file doesn't get deleted, that will prevent renaming the new file. If the old file may still be openend by other services or you don't have the right permissions, you could try to rename it to `path + ".old"` before deleting it. This might move it out of the way even if it can't be deleted. You could also try `file.setWriteable(true)`. It really depends on why the file can't be deleted.

Also, depending on your system setup, the temp file may be created in a location that would require a move instead of a rename (i.e. it is not on the same file system), so `renameTo()` doesn't work.

To address this, don't create a temp file. This is not a temp file really -- it's permanent after the rename. Instead, create a regular file in the same directory as the original file, i.e.

```
File temp = new File(path + ".tmp");
```

This will make sure that both files are on the same file system and a rename will work.

Comment: but this way gives me two files :
1- original.txt
2- original.txt.tmp

Comment: Renaming original.txt.tmp should make it go away. The problem seems to be that original.txt doesn't get deleted in the first place.

Comment: you are right, i checked the original file and found that it's exists even after the delete command. so, what can make me sure that it will be deleted.

Comment: Depends on why it can't be deleted in the first place. You could try file.setWriteable(true). Do you have this problem on a particular platform / file system only? Which permissions are set on the file?

Comment: no, this file i create using my application and there is any problems accessing it

Comment: Did you forget a close() somewhere else perhaps then?

Comment: yea, that's it, a small method used to read some data and i forgot to close the file after using it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It probably doesn't work because there is a service still hanging on to those file; renameTo method is unreliable. Try to test the boolean resulting from that method and see what happens. You'll probably need to do a sleep before releasing the locks associated with the file.

Comment: well,i checked the original file and found that it didn't deleted after the command of deletion , what can make this issue and what can i do to ensure the deletion ?